# Update query with join not working MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

```
UPDATE rates_master
  SET rates_master.fees_information = rates_master_old.fees_information 
from rates_master
  INNER JOIN rates_master_old
    ON rates_master.id=rates_master_old.id;
```

Comment: How is it not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax in MySQL is:

```
UPDATE rates_master rm JOIN
       rates_master_old rmo
       ON rm.id = rmo.id;
    SET rm.fees_information = rmo.fees_information ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following:

```
UPDATE rates_master
SET rates_master.fees_information = rates_master_old.fees_information 
from rates_master, rates_master_old
where rates_master.id=rates_master_old.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE rates_master inner join rates_master_old ON rates_master.id=rates_master_old.id
  SET rates_master.fees_information = rates_master_old.fees_information;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   UPDATE rates_master 
   INNER JOIN rates_master_old ON rates_master.id=rates_master_old.id;
   SET rates_master.fees_information = rates_master_old.fees_information from rates_master
```